# wish missing but tk is installed

Tags: tcl

I was wanting to tinker around with TCL/TK programming.

I tried to invoke the wish shell, but got this error:

```
$ wish
The program 'wish' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install tk
```

So, I tried to apt-get install tk:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
tk is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But it's already installed...

Where did wish go?

UPDATE:

I installed some python-tk packages and now I have wish, but I don't know which package provided it.

However, here is the information requested by the two posters:

Update Alternatives Output:

```
$ update-alternatives --list wish
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for wish
```

LSB Release info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

And now, due to the python-tk packages, when I run the which command I get:

```
$ which -a wish
/usr/bin/wish
```

Lastly, here's where it gets interesting, I asked dpkg who is providing /bin/wish:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/wish
tk: /usr/bin/wish
```

I can only imagine than something was corrected during the install of the python-tk packages...  Otherwise, I'm stumped...  But at least it's working now...

Comment: what is the output of `update-alternatives --list wish`? Please add it to your original post using the 'edit' button.

Comment: What's the output of `lsb_release -a`, `which -a wish wish8.6 wish8.5 wish8.4`, and `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04. A working program trad (from Radiance) stopped working as it required wish (window shell script language like bash). Although latest "tk" was installed on my system, wish was not found.

It seems the program trad was looking for "wish" which had been renamed/ installed as "wish8.6". So a symlink to wish8.6 was created.

I did following to get trad working on my system:

```
sudo ln -sv /usr/bin/wish8.6 /usr/bin/wish
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This problem happens on Ubuntu 20 LTS too. I guess I should have not installed tk8.6, but just tk